# something of particular importance

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> To state or demonstrate something of particular importance.

Above phrase, As a Non-native speaker, I'm not sure what is the relations between 'something' and 'particular importance'. Maybe it's because I simply understand that 'A of B' means B possesses A or A belongs to B or A is a part of B.
By any chance... My guess is 'something of particular importance' means that 'One of the properties something has is particular importance.', right? So I mean, Not only can 'A of B' mean A ⊂ B, Can It also means B ⊂ A sometimes?
So I mean, Is 'something of particular importance' equal to 'something is particular important'?
Sorry for my terrible English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct.

> something of particular importance

means

> something is particularly important

Where both "somethings" refer to a particular fact or property of the subject under discussion.